# Django and Secure iCalendar Feed

Tags: django, feed, icalendar

I would like to create a secure iCalendar Feed with Django.  I currently have a feed working using vobject, but it is accesable to the public.  Is there a way to secure a iCalendar feed used by iCal, Google Calendar, and Outlook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick Google Search shows that most iCal clients support [HTTP Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). You can easily achieve it in Django using [this code snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/243/), providing an useful view decorator.